# How Turn off iPhone's Cellular Radio to ensure Wifi calling is used?

Tags: ipad, wifi-calling

Is this possible?  If so how is this done?  Can this be achieved by clicking on the aircraft icon to put the iPhone in airplane mode?  Assume device is using IOS 12.

Ensuring that calls are made through wifi and not the cellular system is important when roaming.

Assume the it is possible to turn of the cellular radio and forcing wifi callig: Will this prevent the iPad from ringing?

Comment: The tags and all the questions make this a bit confusing. Are you asking about how cellular calls get to an iPad and what to configure to prevent them ringing? Or is this about an iPhone which is where you enable WiFi calling in the first place.

Comment: @bmike  Good questions:  I would like to first understand how to force wifi calling on the iPhone.  Once that is accomplished, I would like to understand if this prevents inbound calls from ringing the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

To restrict telephony to wi-fi only, display the Control Center (on my SE, I slide up from the bottom of the screen to display Control Center), select "Airplane Mode," and then select "Wi-FI" to turn wi-fi on.

I don't know if it'll disable an iPad from ringing.